# CKEditor custom configuration (implemented using WYSIWYG module)

Tags: wysiwyg

How can I set some custom configurations for the CKeditor module? I want to set spell check SCAYT on by default, and a few other things like that. Ideally, I would like to create my own custom config file somewhere sensible that won't be overwritten.

Answer (score 5):

Look at [hook_wysiwyg_settings_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!wysiwyg!wysiwyg.api.php/function/hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter/7)

> Act on editor profile settings.
>
> This hook is invoked from [wysiwyg_get_editor_config()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21wysiwyg%21wysiwyg.module/function/wysiwyg_get_editor_config/7) after the
>   JavaScript settings have been generated for an editor profile and
>   before the settings are added to the page. The settings may be
>   customized or enhanced; typically with options that cannot be
>   controlled through Wysiwyg module's administrative UI currently.
>
> Modules implementing this hook to enforce settings that can also be
>   controlled through the UI should also implement
>   hook_form_wysiwyg_profile_form_alter() to adjust or at least indicate
>   on the editor profile configuration form that certain/affected
>   settings cannot be changed.

Additionally this blog post by [Fuse Interactive: WYSIWYG MODULE + CKEDITOR: TAMING THE BEAST](http://fuseinteractive.ca/blog/wysiwyg-module-ckeditor-taming-beast) goes into great depths on how to make use of this hook. From the blog post ...

```
/**
 * Implements hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter()
 */
function ckeditor_custom_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter(&$settings, $context) {

  // The $context variable contains information about the wysiwyg profile we're using
  // In this case we just need to check that the editor being used is ckeditor

  if ($context['profile']->editor == 'ckeditor') {

    // The $settings variable contains all the config options ckeditor uses. 
    // The array keys correspond directly with any setting that can be applied 
    // to CKEditor - as outlined in the CKEditor docs: 
    // http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html 
    // Another way to override configuration is to use your own configuration javascript
    // file. In this case, we're going to add our own configuration file that will
    // Hold our stylesSet customizations... 
    $settings['customConfig'] = base_path() . drupal_get_path('module', 'ckeditor_custom') .
                                '/ckeditor_custom_config.js';

    // We are also going to specify a custom body id and class
    $settings['bodyId'] = 'ckeditor_custom_id';
    $settings['bodyClass'] = 'ckeditor_custom_class';

    // To see what's in $settings and $context, install the devel module 
    // And run the variables through the dpm() function. 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code inspired by @tenken

```
/**
 * Implements hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter()
 *
 * @see http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Enabling_SCAYT
 */
function modulename_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter(&$settings, $context) {
  // The $context variable contains information about the wysiwyg profile we're using
  // In this case we just need to check that the editor being used is ckeditor
  if ($context['profile']->editor == 'ckeditor') {
    // Make Scayt enabled by default.
    $settings['scayt_autoStartup'] = 'true';
  }
}
```