# Is it possible to add translation to smiley alt and title in CKEditor?

Tags: wysiwyg

I'm using Drupal 7 with CKEditor module which permit to insert smiley from editor. I've found that the source code of CKEditor fix the smiley description in JS :

```
config.smiley_descriptions = [
    'smiley', 'sad', 'wink', 'laugh', 'frown', 'cheeky', 'blush', 'surprise',
    'indecision', 'angry', 'angel', 'cool', 'devil', 'crying', 'enlightened', 'no',
    'yes', 'heart', 'broken heart', 'kiss', 'mail'
];
```

So when I insert a smiley, the code will be

```
<img alt="laugh" height="23" src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.3/full-all/plugins/smiley/images/teeth_smile.png" title="laugh" width="23">
```

But I want to modify the language of `alt` and `title` attributs according to the language  used in my site.  Is it possible to do that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you finally work it out?

Answer (score 0):

Never tried but I'm pretty sure that's possible.

If you use the `ckeditor` module, you can alter JS settings through PHP with `hook_ckeditor_settings_alter`.

Knowing that, it becomes pretty easy to wrap all strings with the [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function:

```
function yourmodule_ckeditor_settings_alter(&$settings, $conf) {
  foreach ($settings['smiley_descriptions'] as $key => $smiley) {
    $settings['smiley_descriptions'][$key] = t($settings['smiley_descriptions'][$key]);
  }
}
```

If you use the `wysiwyg_ckeditor` module, you can use `hook_wysiwyg_plugin`. That's pretty much the same thing, you can find a pretty good example on how to use this hook [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/108239/3751).

Again, the code hasn't been tested, but it should be a good starting point ;).